# Google Sheets character sort order

Tags: google-sheets

Is there anywhere where I can find the list google uses when you a-z sort a list with a filter? 
EDIT: Image for clarity:

[image: Image of a Google Sheets Filter]

More specifically, I need a character that is discreet; ideally a blank character; that is sorted after the plus sign '+'.

Comment: I've added a picture that should explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've made a test. You may see the result in [Sample File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1y0bws_Z7xT0EymiU7wW5l80ns6n7BOpe23SIILvghSA):

[image]

I tried first 3000 chars:

- Column A: numbers from 1 to 3000
- Column B: char formula: `=CHAR(A2)`

I sorted the range with filter and got an unexpected result: Google is not using [`ASCII`](http://www.asciitable.com/) to sort text.

Also, see `sort` function works the same way as sort by a filter. But sorting with `query` gives another result.

---

When I tried the same experiment in Excel I was confused even more:

- `=CHAR(A2)` gives another result in Excel, it not an `ASCII` char
- sorting range of chars gives different from Sheets result. Please try it yourself to see.