# Google Sheets strings comparator

Tags: google-sheets, string-comparison

Could anyone tell what exact strings comparing algorithm is used in Google Sheets?

I try to use an array of data sorted by Google Sheets and seems that it's not usable for binary search. For example, Google Sheets thinks that

`0`(48) > `|`(124)

`-`(45) > `_`(95)

and so on.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Sheets character sort order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46913169/google-sheets-character-sort-order)

Comment: @I'-'I, it's not the exact answer but gives a clue. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is solved. I had to create a map of ASCII -> Google Sheet indices and apply it in my own comparator. Thanks to @I'-'I for sharing "possible duplicate" to [Google Sheets character sort order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46913169/google-sheets-character-sort-order)